# Power shell Multiple WMI commands within if statement

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am just starting out with powershell and I have the following script:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | 

ForEach-Object {

  if(Test-Connection -CN $_.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet)

    {   
   write-host $_.dnshostname
   Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -cn $_.dnshostname | Select     ProcessID,ProcessName,ThreadCount
   Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive -cn $_.dnshostname;
   }



  ELSE { write-host $_.dnshostname unavlible }

}
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is pull from my DC a list of every computer, test if they are up and then poll them with multiple WMI queries. The problem I am having is that when I am doing my select on the first Wmi object is that I then dont a result of the second wmi object as I am assuming the select is being applied to the second object causing no data to be returned.

Any idea how I can do this. Also right now I am using a ping to test a machine avalibility but this is not the best as ICMP is blocked on some systems but WMI is still possible. The same goes for ICMP being available but wmi blocked. Is there a better way to perform the test of getting a list of systems that the WMI query will work?

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround  that I've found from powershell v1 to v3 is doing:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |     
ForEach-Object {    
  if(Test-Connection -CN $_.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet)    
   {   
     write-host $_.dnshostname
     Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -cn $_.dnshostname | 
     Select ProcessID,ProcessName,ThreadCount
     out-string -inputobject "" #this line does the trick or just out-default
     Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive -cn $_.dnshostname;
   }
  else { write-host "$($_.dnshostname) unavailable }    
}
```

For testing  availability server I use [this function](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Test-Server-e0cdea9a)  it uses ping and other protocol to see if a server is up, you need just a `true` to know if is  alive.
(As sysadmin a suggest in a domain (not in a DMZ domain) to enable `icmp` protocol as first diagnostic tools)